# Trouble linking the consumer key to my Soundcloud using application.js

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to recreate the link in my own personal site. I have included all files that are necessary, and linked to them accordingly. I followed the instructions from this page http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com/docs/application.html and at the point where it says Pass a consumer key, which can be created here, and your playlist url. I created an app and copied the client_id which I'm presuming is the "consumer key" and put in the link to a set i created. For some reason it doesn't seem to be working. Am I supposed to fill in all the fields when creating the app or are they not necessary? I'm building in my localhost, am I supposed to be live for it to take affect?

Here is what I am trying to achieve working, I just don't know where I'm going wrong. http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com

Comment: What code do you have? What have you already tried? The music seems to play and the links to next and previous song work.

Comment: The link i attached is what I followed to create my own. I have put all the correct files in the only difference is the 'consumer key' and the link to my set of music. I think I'm going wrong when I click on the link to create the consumer key. No music is playing. Do you have any guidance as to what to do when you set up the consumer key?

Comment: From what I understand everything stays the same except this part 

var consumer_key = "ePT3qXXTOjw4ZoZcN7ALQ",
url = "http://soundcloud.com/foofighters/sets/wasting-light";

Comment: I worked out where I was going wrong - I wasn't linking to the swf folder for soundmanager2 properly. That's why is wasn't working.